# How to use Expo Camera in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

Expo Camera is working in my code.

**Current Code**

```js
const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
if (status === 'granted') {
  const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    allowsEditing: true,
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
  });
}
```

if status === 'granted', camera opens.

**What I want to do**

I wanna change text 'Cancel' to Japanese on the bottom.

Is there any way to set locale?

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

[image: camera]

Answer (score 0):

The dialog block should be native and language should becomes your phone's setting language, maybe you could try to change your phone to Japanese local and restart the app.

If you want to customer the dialog, you could detect and using `Alert.alert` to show what you want to show, but request may be native to ask again.

Something like this I used before:

```js
Alert.alert(
  I18n.t('Permission_requireTitle'),
  I18n.t('Permission_camera'),
  [
    {
      text: I18n.t('Permission_btn1'),
      onPress: () => {
        console.log("Permission denied");
        Actions.pop();
      },
      style: "cancel"
    },
    {
      text: I18n.t('Permission_btn3'),
      onPress: () => {        
        AndroidOpenSettings.appDetailsSettings();
      }
    }
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
);
```

Or maybe it have language setting in your permission package you could try to find.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to find how to set language in this package.